# how to refer a xml bean to another bean that is configured based on annotation

Tags: spring, annotations

My xml config is like this

```
<bean id="empBean" class="com.demo.Employee"> 
    <property name="empId" value="01234"/>  
    <property name="age" value="25"></property> 
    <property name="add"><ref bean="AddObj"/></property> 
</bean>
```

Here the 'AddObj' is beanObject that is configured based on annotation.How do I link that in this xml file?

Comment: Be specific what you want to ask, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way to reference the @Bean with the xml is with the method name you are anotating take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html.

If you want to set a name to your @Bean anotatated method you can do so by 
`@Bean(name = "myCoolBean")` You'll then reference in the Xml with `myCoolBean`

It doesen't matter how it got created XML,annotation, metadata. Every bean ends up in the application context under a unique name.

Same works for @Service and @Componenet annotatios

```
  @Service("myCoolService")

<bean class="com.a.cool.Class">
  <property name="someProp" ref="myCoolService"/>
</bean>
```

Hope it helps